Compare two arrays in typescript to filter items from first array
I have two arrays
PhoneTypesAll:
[
{"Id":"3","DisplayName":"Fax"},
{"Id":"1","DisplayName":"Home"},
{"Id":"4","DisplayName":"Mobile"},
{"Id":"2","DisplayName":"Office"},
{"Id":"5","DisplayName":"Other"}
]

PhoneTypesSelected:
[
{"PhoneNumberId":127436,"ContactId":22222,"IsPrimary":true, "PhoneType":  {"Id":"2","DisplayName":"Office"},"PhoneNumber":"111111111","Extension":"","DisplayPhoneNumber":"111-111-1111"},
{"PhoneNumberId":127437,"ContactId":22222,"IsPrimary":false,"PhoneType":{"Id":"3","DisplayName":"Fax"},"PhoneNumber":"111111111","Extension":null,"DisplayPhoneNumber":"111-111-1111"},
{"PhoneNumberId":173825,"ContactId":22222,"IsPrimary":false,"PhoneType":{"Id":"4","DisplayName":"Mobile"},"PhoneNumber":"111111111","Extension":"","DisplayPhoneNumber":"111-111-1111"}
]

In TypeScript, I need to filter array 1 (PhoneTypesAll - 5 records) to only show Phone Types not in array 2 (PhoneTypesSelected-3 records).
I have tried this filter but is not filtering correctly.
this.sourcePhoneTypes = this.PhoneTypesAll.filter(item => !this.PhoneTypesSelected.some(itemToBeRemoved => itemToBeRemoved['Id'] == item['Id']));
End Result needs to show array 1 filtered as:
PhoneTypesAll:
[
{"Id":"1","DisplayName":"Home"},    
{"Id":"5","DisplayName":"Other"}
]


Please show the code that is not working as a [mre] in a Stack Snippet.

I expect it has something to do with itemToBeRemoved not being a PhoneType (i.e., not having an Id property). You probably want itemToBeRemoved.PhoneType.Id

Try making the list of IDs you don't need and then filter the first list


var PhoneTypesAll = 
[
{"Id":"3","DisplayName":"Fax"},
{"Id":"1","DisplayName":"Home"},
{"Id":"4","DisplayName":"Mobile"},
{"Id":"2","DisplayName":"Office"},
{"Id":"5","DisplayName":"Other"}
];

var PhoneTypesSelected = 
    [
    {"PhoneNumberId":127436,"ContactId":22222,"IsPrimary":true, "PhoneType":  {"Id":"2","DisplayName":"Office"},"PhoneNumber":"111111111","Extension":"","DisplayPhoneNumber":"111-111-1111"},
    {"PhoneNumberId":127437,"ContactId":22222,"IsPrimary":false,"PhoneType":{"Id":"3","DisplayName":"Fax"},"PhoneNumber":"111111111","Extension":null,"DisplayPhoneNumber":"111-111-1111"},
    {"PhoneNumberId":173825,"ContactId":22222,"IsPrimary":false,"PhoneType":{"Id":"4","DisplayName":"Mobile"},"PhoneNumber":"111111111","Extension":"","DisplayPhoneNumber":"111-111-1111"}
    ]

var IdsToExclude = PhoneTypesSelected.map(a=> a.PhoneType?.Id)
var result = PhoneTypesAll.filter(item => !IdsToExclude.includes(item.Id))

console.log(result)




I'm getting this error message in TypeScript:
Property 'PhoneType' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

add a "?" after phoneType while finding IdsToExclude, updated in answer

Never mind my last comment, I had to make my arrays defined with type 'any'. Its working now. Thanks
